# Set SSL on IIS8

Tags: iis, ssl, aspdotnetstorefront

Greeting,

I have installation of AspDotNetStoreFront on Amazon (Server 2012 and IIS8).
That cart need to be connected to StoneEdge software. We purchased a script (for our cart) from StoneEdge. So far we have been unable to connect.
StoneEdge support told me that I need to have a SSL Certificate in place. But I cant have it, since the site is still in test phase. I have seen on MSDN that I cant set SSL until I have valid SSL Certificate.

Is there a way to set up generic/dummy certificate so we can test it?
In my opinion I do not think SSL is required for testing purposes... or I am wrong?

Comment: offtopic.google for "self-signed certificate"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not a SSL certificate is required to connect with StoneEdge, really depends on their integration requirements. In other words, yes it may be valid that a SSL certificate is required.

A SSL certificate can certainly be created/acquired for testing purposes. However, you will have to determine what type of certificate will support your testing needs.

For example, when appropriate I may use a self-signed certificate. In other instances, I may need a certificate signed by a trusted CA. It may also be useful to note that some providers, like Comodo, offer free trial SSL certificates.